# Width of dialog when used in a loop

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a problem controlling the width of a dialog, when I use it in a loop (I have a dialog for each option in a for loop).
My code is based on this example: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#entry-examples , and when I run this example as it is, the width function is working perfectly.
Adding the loop function, then the widht does not work.

Anyone who knows what is wrong?

My code:

```
<?php    
$cars = array("Audi", "BMW", "Mercedes");

for($n=0;$n< sizeof($cars);$n++)
{
    echo '<button class = "opener" index='.$n.'>'.$cars[$n].'</button> <br>';

    echo '<div id="dialog-'.$n.'" title="'.$cars[$n].'">';
        echo 'hey';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$( function() {
    var i;
    $( "#dialog-"+i ).dialog({ 
        autoOpen: false,
        height: '400',
        width: '600',
        modal: true,

        close: function() {
        }
    });

    $('.opener').on("click", function(){
        i = this.getAttribute("index");
        $('#dialog-'+i).dialog().dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
} );
</script>
```

Comment: what is the value of `i` in the loop

Comment: @DVP , any errors in your console ?

Comment: You pass `string` but dialog expects the value to be `number`.

Comment: @ArunPJohny - The value of `i` is the same as `$n`, so it is from 0 to 2.
@AlexanderSolonik - I don't get any errors in console.
@lolbas - I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: @DVP you pass `width` and `height` params as strings. According to the link you provided it should be number, i.e. not `width: '600'` but `width: 600`.

Comment: @lolbas - Ah thanks, but sadly it does not solve the problem :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    var i;
    var objDialogOptions = {
        autoOpen: false,
        height: '400',
        width: '600',
        modal: true,
        close: function () {
           //Callback on close of dialog
        }
    };

    $('.opener').on("click", function () {
        i = this.getAttribute("index");
        $('#dialog-' + i).dialog(objDialogOptions).dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Hope this will fix the problem